# Hystrix Request Caching by Example

Tags: java, caching, fault-tolerance, hystrix

I am trying to figure out how [Hystrix request caching](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/How-To-Use#Caching) works but am not following the wiki or end-to-end examples they provide in their docs.

Essentially I have the following `HystrixCommand` subclass:

```
public class GetFizzCommand extends HystrixCommand<Fizz> {
    private Long id;
    private Map<Long,Fizz> fizzCache = new HashMap<Long,Fizz>();

    void doExecute(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
        execute();
    }

    @Override
    public Fizz run() {
        return getFizzSomehow();
    }

    @Override
    public Fizz getFallback() {
        // Consult a cache somehow.
        // Perhaps something like a Map<Long,Fizz> where the 'id' is the key (?)
        // If the 'id' exists in the cache, return it. Otherwise, give up and return
        // NULL.
        fizzCache.get(id);
    }
}
```

So I feel like I'm going against the grain here. I *believe* Hystrix offers built-in caching, as is evidenced by a ['`cacheKey`'](http://netflix.github.io/Hystrix/javadoc/index.html?com/netflix/hystrix/HystrixCommand.html#getCacheKey()), but I can't find any working examples. I don't want to reinvent the wheel here and build caching into my commands if something is already provided out of the box.

So I ask: what does request caching look like with Hystrix (exactly)? How are entries added to the cache? How/when is the cache flushed? Is it configurable (expiries, max sizes, etc.)?

Comment: You could read up the implementation of HystrixCommand. A starting point would be the method [HystrixCommand.isResponseFromCache())](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.netflix.hystrix/hystrix-core/1.3.3/com/netflix/hystrix/HystrixCommand.java#HystrixCommand.isResponseFromCache()) (links to *grepcode.com*).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Per the documentation you linked to [here](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/How-To-Use#Caching),

> Request caching is enabled by implementing the `getCacheKey()` method on a `HystrixCommand` object...

You haven't implemented `getCacheKey()`,

```
@Override
protected String getCacheKey() {
    return String.valueOf(id); // <-- changed from `value` in example
}
```

Then you also need a [`HystrixRequestContext`](http://netflix.github.io/Hystrix/javadoc/com/netflix/hystrix/strategy/concurrency/HystrixRequestContext.html)

```
HystrixRequestContext context = HystrixRequestContext.initializeContext();
```

Which is (again, per the documentation)

> Typically this context will be initialized and shutdown via a `ServletFilter` that wraps a user request or some other lifecycle hook.

Then I believe you cannot change the method signature of [`execute()`](http://netflix.github.io/Hystrix/javadoc/index.html?com/netflix/hystrix/HystrixCommand.html#execute%28%29) like that (`doExecute()` isn't part of the interface) instead you pass the parameter to your command constructor and please annotate `execute` with an `@Override` so you get a compiler error if you forget  and then

```
HystrixRequestContext context = HystrixRequestContext.initializeContext();
GetFizzCommand commandA = new GetFizzCommand(2L);
GetFizzCommand commandB = new GetFizzCommand(2L);
Fizz a = commandA.execute(); // <-- should not be cached
Fizz b = commandB.execute(); // <-- should be cached.
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a HystrixRequestContext in your controller

```
//init
HystrixRequestContext context = HystrixRequestContext.initializeContext();
// get cache logic ...

//close
context.close();
```

The better way is that you add a filter class.

```
import com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixRequestContext;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter;
import java.io.IOException;

@Component
@WebFilter(urlPatterns = "/*", asyncSupported = true)
public class HystrixRequestContextFilter implements Filter {
  @Override
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HystrixRequestContext context = HystrixRequestContext.initializeContext();
    try {
      filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
    } finally {
      context.close();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `@HystrixCommand`，you can use `@com.netflix.hystrix.contrib.javanica.cache.annotation.CacheKey` on the method parameter to generate request cache key,

```java
@Component
public class SpringBootMockRemoteService {

    @HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod = "fallback")
    public String getRemoteValue(@CacheKey String username) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(3_000);
        return "SUCCESS";
    }

    String fallback() {
        return "FALLBACK";
    }
}
```

request cache key will be the value of the parameter `username`